# Fetching data into UITableView with fail safes

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm fetching data from an API using NSURLConnection and NSHTTPURLResponse, but I'm not sure of the best (or a good) way to display an error if no data is returned. As it is now, I just don't show anything. Basically just setting the UITableView datasource to nil.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *seriesReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/"]];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:seriesReq returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
            NSError *error;

            seriesJson = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];

            [_seriesTableView reloadData];
        }
        else {
            seriesJson = nil;
        }
    });
});
```

I was thinking of maybe just populating seriesJson with a dummy data set and then if-checking that inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to be able to show it, but for some reason it doesn't strike me as a good solution.

How do I present to the user that the data requested is empty or not usable?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you expect the user to do with the information you provide.  If you just want to inform them there is an error (and no recourse) then setting a prompt on the Navigation bar may suffice.  If there is an action the user can take, then a UIAlert with a retry button (or other) may be appropriate.